# Catch all scroll events on page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need a little help.
I have created my own context menu for right click and I want it to behave like classic one - to dissapear after scroll. But the problem is that I have more scrollbars in my layout, so the question is, how to catch all scroll events on the page? I have tried for examle `$(document).scroll()` but it works only for main scrollbar, I have tried also to use `.on("scroll", function(){});` on the main container, but this doesn't work at all :(

So any ideas please?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding classes to your scrollable elements, such as class="scrollable", and then do a selector on that class. It requires some dirty work in adding the class, but it will efficiently get the job done.

```
$(document).add('.scrollable').on('scroll', function() {
    alert("Action here");
});
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work, it is still working only for main scrollbar. I am using `<div id="okno1_textBox" class="textBox">
            <div id="okno1_text" class="oknoText">
            </div>
            </div>`  
the .textBox has overflow set to auto and to ,oknoText I am loading data so I tried `$(document).add(".textBox").on('scroll',function () { alert("test"); });` but nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add them manually:

```
$("html, body, #yourMainDiv, .scrolling, #whatever").on("scroll", function(){...});
```